# How to format HTML in .csv for import into Enhance Dynamic Content - SFMC

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

with Enhanced Dynamic Content - you have to upload a .csv file and each column will turn into an EDC Map Content Block.  I then create the email and drag in the Enhanced Dynamic Content Block.  Each cell has to contain the proper HTML formatting as you cannot do that once it's been uploaded.  I can get everything to work except muli-line text - or text with line breaks in it.  I'm not sure if I'm formatting the HTML incorrectly - or if EDC does not support line breaks.  In which case I would have to create a copy column for each paragraph - and that does not sound right.

Too much.  I've tried adding 
 between sentences.  I've tried inserting line breaks in an Excel version of the document - then saving as .csv - this is supposed to insert some double quotes somewhere but does not.

"""""At The Hanover, we’re excited to make our latest move into the state of %%BillingState%%.
As a New England-based company with national reach, we value local, independent agents and all you do to help ensure your customers have the right protections in place.
We look forward to launching our personal lines products and services in %%BillingState%% in partnership with select independent agents."""""

The custom text for the cell above does not display - rather it displays one line text from the default row.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue.

What I found worked in my instance was to add `<p> Your text </P>`, so that when you import it, it should respect the line breaks.

Comment: sorry it stripped out part of it but it was an html paragraph.

Comment: Your answer doesn't have any code. Would you like to edit and submit it?

Comment: I have had the same problem - i include code and then it's stripped out when I post the question